# Wordpress - show last 5 posts - leave reply issue

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I made a question previously on SO to get help with a show last 5 posts from specific category issue. This was resolved, but presented a new issue and is ONLY apparent when i use the shortcode.

**The issue**

Using the code below, when i add the shortcode to one of my pages, it adds a "Leave a reply" box at the bottom of the page. I have comments turned off and the "Leave a reply" is not apparent on the site when the shortcode is NOT used - it only happens when i add the shortcode, which leads me to believe the issue is related to the PHP code below which is added to my functions.php.

**The code**

```
function Last5posts()   {
    $args = array( 'showposts' => 5, 'cat' => '3');                  
    $last_5_posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while($last_5_posts_query->have_posts()) : 
    $last_5_posts_query->the_post();
    $link = get_permalink();
    $title = get_the_title();
    $date = get_the_date();                              

    $content .= '<div class="latest-posts">';
    $content .= '<h3><a href='.$link.' target="_top">'.$title.' / '.$date. '</a></h3>';
    $content .= '<p class="excerpt">' .get_the_excerpt(). '</p>';
    $content .= '</div>';
endwhile;

return $content;
}

add_shortcode('Last5Posts', 'Last5posts' );
```

Comment: What does `get_the_excerpt()` look like?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Are you asking what the output is?

Comment: I'm wondering if `get_the_excerpt()` includes the leave a reply. You can test it by changing it to: `$content .= '<p class="excerpt">Test</p>';` and see if that removes the reply link.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but the leave a reply is still there. I will try it with the rest of the hooks to see if one of them are the cause.

Comment: @NikkiMather out of curiosity why use a shortcode? and please post the place where you use that shortcode... such as in the php code or in a page/post editor, etc

Comment: David, i use a shortcode to give me more flexibility of where i can use the code and i find it much easier to work with, rather than directly adding it to theme files. I use the short code in the page editor directly and the PHP code itself is contained in the functions.php.

Comment: that page that uses the shortcode has `allow comments` unchecked correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by "showposts" being depricated, replaced it with "post_per_page" and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You use custom WP_Query in your code. When you call the_post() on your query, the global $post variable changes. So the code running after your shortcode method will work with your new $post value.

Add wp_reset_postdata after endwhile and it should be OK.